# what is the scope and right way to define PDF access class in spring.?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, pdf

i have a pdf class for creating,accesing,viewing pdf actions, and i dnt know that, what should be right way to access PDF classes in spring ie.

JSF  scope,
Spring Bean Scope'
naming structure
etc..
what are the dos and dnts...with brief explanation..it would be a great help..I am new in this and i need in Spring only..not in SpringMVC.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

get spring pdf example by following url

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-web-mvc-with-pdf-view-example-using-itext-5x

hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for your valuable response !! but i am not getting the link..Please suggest some more reference that basically focus on jasper report!
thank you

Comment: http://keytotechnologies.blogspot.in/2013/02/jasper-report-spring-hibernate-example.html

use this link